# Breaking up 2D matrix to Value;Heading format

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently dealing with a fairly large (in excess of 100MB) sheet that is formatted as follows:

```
a;b;c;d;
1;2;3;4;
5;6;7;8;
9;;10;11;
;;12;;
```

i.e. it is a two-dimensional matrix with columns of uneven length.

I am trying to rewrite this monstrosity into the following format, coordinating each value with its respective first-line value:

```
1;a
5;a
9;a
2;b
6;b
3;c
7;c
10;c
12;c ...
```

So far my main opponent is the challenge of having to identify the coordinates of each single value. Since any lookup solution I have found always requires either line or column to be known, I assume that only a script can solve this. However, when I am dealing with scripts, there might yet be an easier solution to rewrite this table than one that relies on excessive searching.

What would be the best way to solve this, potentially using VBA? I'd appreciate any help with this!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow, the site exists to help you with your coding problem, therefore if you include no code there's nothing for us to help you with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though you didn't post any code, I think that's ok for me to help you because I once had the exact same problem.

The next code will write the matrix you asked for on columns `E` and `F`:

```
Sub StackOverflow()
    Dim counter As Long: counter = 1
    Dim x As Long: Dim y As Integer
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stack")
        For y = 1 To 4
            For x = 1 To .Columns(y).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
                If .Cells(x, y).Value <> "" Then
                    .Cells(counter, 5).FormulaR1C1 = .Cells(x, y).Value
                    .Cells(counter, 6).FormulaR1C1 = ColumnAddress(y)
                    counter = counter + 1
                End If
            Next x
        Next y
    End With
End Sub
Function ColumnAddress(y As Integer) As String
    Select Case y
        Case 1: ColumnAddress = "a"
        Case 2: ColumnAddress = "b"
        Case 3: ColumnAddress = "c"
        Case 4: ColumnAddress = "d"
    End Select
End Function
```

Feel free to adjust the code addresses to your situation (i.e. Worksheets names, Macro names and cells addresses).

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. You would also probably want to optimize the code given the size of the file a loop will take a long time. https://analystcave.com/excel-improve-vba-performance/